# Who is to be credited for Aaron Satie's wisdom in "The Drumhead"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes, quotes

The following quote is from one of my favourite *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episodes, ["The Drumhead" (4x21)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Drumhead_(episode)). It is cited by Picard and attributed to the fictional Judge Aaron Satie:

> With the first link, the chain is forged. The first speech censured, the first thought forbidden, the first freedom denied, chains us all irrevocably.
>
> *Picard, quoting Judge Aaron Satie*

According to Memory Alpha (see link), *Jeri Taylor* is to be credited for writing of this episode. However, are these actually *her* words? Or was she quoting somebody herself? Or was the episode co-written by an uncredited second person who contributed the quote?

**Yes, I am asking for an out-of-universe answer.**

Comment: What makes you wonder if this bit of dialog was written by someone other than the writer of the episode, especially when that writer was Jeri Taylor?

Comment: @MarkBeadles: So much emphasis was put on it, that I suspected it was actually a quote that precedes that episode. But due to Star Trek saturation, Google is useless.

Comment: If the quote is hard to find, it's probably Jeri Taylor's own writing.  If she were going to lift a line from some other writer it would be someone well-known enough to be obviously attributible (e.g. Shakespeare, Melville), otherwise Taylor be open to a plagiarism charge were it ever found out.

Comment: @KyleJones: My assumption was that it's only hard to find because the web has now associated that quote with Star Trek. Does this make any sense? Anyway, I think I get your point.

Comment: A lot of people use that quote as their email tag, making it even harder to see if there's a source other than Ms. Taylor (I tried doing an exclusion search, subtracting any Star Trek reference words). If it *is* her own words, then I wish she had received more credit - it's a powerful and moving statement.

Comment: I suggest you attempt to e-mail or contact Jeri Taylor, herself, and ask her if she came up with that or was it some vague concoction of someone else's words.

Answer (score 6):

Jeri Taylor, as she was credited with writing the episode.

As you've previously pointed out, StarTrek saturation makes it difficult to find in reference to anyone other than Jean-Luc Picard, but I did find [one reference](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/418778-you-know-there-are-some-words-i-ve-known-since-i).

Comment: That reference doesn't make it clear to me! It looks like a quote attributed to Gene Roddenberry, but inside that quote he's quoting the fictional Judge Aaron Satie!!

Comment: @AidanO - Roddenberry died Oct '91, but TNG season 4 was aired 90-91 (so must have been written before that), so maybe the web site is mis-attributing it or Roddenberry and Taylor came up with it together (or something else entirely). It's the only reference I could find that isn't attributed to Captain Picard.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same quote and could not find a reference in English. However, when I translated it into German, I found it.
The quote is by French composer Alfred Éric Leslie Satie. Yes, the character name is probably a nod to him. 
No copyright infringement or plagiarism, since Msr. Satie passed away in 1925.

Comment: Interesting! Can you provide a source, any link with more info, ...?

Comment: Yes, a source would be very useful. Is the quote in French or German?

Comment: “No copyright infringement or plagiarism, since Msr. Satie passed away in 1925.” — In the UK I believe copyright lasts for 70 years from the author’s death, so Msr. Satie’s copyright would only have expired here in 1995, after the episode first aired.

Comment: Discussed extensively on MemoryAlpha Germany. Identified as "*probably a hoax*"; http://de.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Diskussion:Aaron_Satie

Comment: Several people have indicated that this page is the source; http://www.zitate-online.de/literaturzitate/allgemein/18916/mit-dem-ersten-glied-ist-die-kette-geschmiedet.html. No citation provided and the quote *appears* to be a google translation of the quote from the episode.

Comment: I just arrived at the same conclusion as @Valorum. Still an interesting find,  but evidence seems to point to a misattribution of the translated Aaron Satie quote at some point.

Comment: What is most telling is that the translation is a **word-for-word** translation. When was the last time you saw Google Translate manage to actually get a direct quote completely right? Never, that's when.

Answer (score -2):

[Erik Satie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erik_Satie), actually [Alfred Éric Leslie Satie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erik_Satie#Writings) was a French composer and pianist.

*17.05.1866 in Honfleur (Calvados), France
† 01.07.1925 in Paris, France

> „Mit dem ersten Glied ist die Kette geschmiedet. Wenn die erste Rede
> zensiert, der erste Gedanke verboten, die erste Freiheit verweigert
> wird, dann sind wir alle unwiderruflich gefesselt.“

French:

> Dès le 1er maillon, la chaîne est forgée. La 1ère parole censurée, la
> 1ère idée bannie, la 1ère liberté écrasée. On nous enchaîne
> irrévocablement.

Possible context:

> dont un proche avait disparu dans l’enfer de la dictature militaire,
> avaient inlassablement tourné en procession à Buenos Aires pour
> obtenir justice, et qu’on se souvienne de la liberté écrasée par un
> régime criminel. Et d’ailleurs le temps d’une justice sans
> prescription semble enfin venu en Argentine, donnant raison à ces «
> Folles » en lutte contre les tortionnaires, ceux de leur pays et de
> tant d’autres contrées passées et présentes…Vox Humana « se sert des
> mots, mais les déstructure et les hache, alternant chuchotements,
> silences et cris pour dire l’émotion indicible ».

English translation:

> whose loved one had disappeared in the hell of the military
> dictatorship, had tirelessly turned in procession in Buenos Aires to
> obtain justice, and that we remember the freedom crushed by a criminal
> regime. And besides, the time for justice without limitation finally
> seems to have come to Argentina, giving reason to these "Crazy women"
> fighting against the torturers, those of their country and of so many
> other past and present countries...Vox Humana (the voice of humanity) «uses words, but
> deconstructs them and chops them up, alternating whispers, silences
> and cries to express the unspeakable emotion»”.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  As you may have noted, this has been suggested already, but the veracity is disputed.  Can you provide a refutation of [the link](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/de/wiki/Diskussion:Aaron_Satie) provided in the comment?